# Below code prints 0,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,0 Modify only functions ( not loops ) to get output as 4,3,2,1,0,0,1,2,3,4

Tags: javascript

Please help me in writing required code.
Below code prints 0,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,0 Modify only functions ( not loops ) to get output as 4,3,2,1,0,0,1,2,3,4

```js
var a = function(i) {
  console.log(i);
};
var b = function(i) {
  console.log(i);
};
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  a(i);
}
for (var i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
  b(i);
}
```

Comment: Change both too -> `console.log(4-i);`

Comment: Thanks Keith, I have already tried this solution, but just wanted to know if there are any other methods other than hardcoding (4-i)

Answer (score 1):

You could set a timeout which postpone the output.

```js
var a = function(i) {
        setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
    },
    b = function(i) {
        console.log(i);
    },
    i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) a(i);
for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--) b(i);
```